# Spring Cloud Dataflow aggregation of splitted list

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to use SCDF to split and aggregate my list. But I can't aggregate as expected.
 
My SCDF is being fed by a list over rabbitmq each minute. Let's say i have a list consisting of objects like:

```
[{"foo" : "11", "bar" : "21"},{"foo" : "11", "bar" : "22"},{"foo" : "12", "bar" : "23"}]
```

I am splitting the array into the objects in splitter as: `app.splitter.expression=#jsonPath(payload,'$.[*]')` and it is working as expected.
And in the aggregator, I want to aggregate them based on the value of the property `foo`, so that the result of aggregation should be two different arrays like:

```
[{"foo" : "11", "bar" : "21"},{"foo" : "11", "bar" : "22"}]
[{"foo" : "12", "bar" : "23"}]
```

I set the `correlation` as: `app.aggregator.correlation=#jsonPath(payload,'$.foo')` but I dont know how to set `release` SpEL expression.
Can you show me how should i set `release`?

PS: As a workaround, I tried to add a last object to the list for detecting it is the end of the list. So, I add `{{"foo" : "EoS"}` object to the list. And in the `release` I tried: `app.aggregator.release=!messages.?[new String(payload).contains("EoS")].empty` but it didn't work.

Comment: here is an example; https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/aggregator/blob/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-processor-aggregator/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/aggregator/processor/AggregatorProcessorTests.java